# Missing Settings after Project creation in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded a fresh copy of Android Studio and created a new Project.

But afaik there are missing a lot of Settings:

[image: current screenshot]

But AFAIK it should be something like this:

[image: should be like this]

So there are Missing a lot of project settings like

- Project
- Libraries
- Facets
- Artifacts

How can i Achieve that the Settings appear?

Comment: Update Android Studio to last version 0.3.7.

Comment: i did, still missing.

Answer (score 4):

This is working as intended. The settings you're used to seeing don't apply to Gradle-based projects, which your project is. Adjusting those settings would get your project into a weird state that could cause a lot of problems later on. For Gradle-based projects, all changes to project configuration need to happen through the `build.gradle` file. The UI that you see under the **Modules** option can take care of a lot of that, but it's incomplete as of now.

If you're using a non-Gradle based project, then those options will appear as you need them to work with those project types.

Comment: Way a lot effort to find the reason... make sense.